# How to get rid of comma at the end of printing from loop

Tags: python

So basically I have the list of many points and I want to extract only unique values.
I have written a function but I have 1 problem: how to avoid printing comma at the end of the list?

```
def unique(list1):
    unique_values = []
    for u in list1:
        if u not in unique_values:
            unique_values.append(u)
    for u in unique_values:
        print(u, end=", ")


wells = ["U1", "U1", "U3", "U3", "U3", "U5", "U5", "U5", "U7", "U7", "U7", "U7", "U7", "U8", "U8"]
print("The unique values from list are...:", end=" ")
unique(wells)
```

my output is for now: "The unique values from list are...: U1, U3, U5, U7, U8,"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be an overkill but you can use `NumPy` "unique" method, which is probably more efficient, a specially for large arrays or long lists.

The following code will do:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd'])
y = np.unique(x)
print(', '.join(y))
```

and the result is:

```
a, b, c, d
```

**Added in Edit:** the following solution works also for non-string lists.

```
''' Print unique values in a list or numpy array '''

x = [1, 2, 2, 5, 7, 1, 3]
print(x)

# set(x) will return a set of the unique values of x
u = set(x)
print(u)

# remove the curly brackets
str_u = str(u).strip("}{")
print(str_u)
```

and the result is

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 7
```

Comment: You can use `', '.join(set(values))`. Don't need numpy

Comment: This solution works when the set of values is a set or list of strings.

Comment: I installed NumPy and all works as intended (thanks!) but....... what about the situation when I have a point labelled as for example U10 or U20, I mean when I add a sampling point to the list with a number >10 it goes on position 2 on my list after printing etc. 

for example: U1, U10, U20, U3, U30, U5, U7, U8

What I would like though, is numbers in "rising" order after U, so for example:
"U1, U3, U5, U7, U8, U10, U20, U30" is what I expect my output to be. 

How can I arrange that?

Comment: @Triceratops The OP is asking about strings, no?

Comment: @crtnnn Ordering is not preserved when finding unique elements. You need to re-sort the data afterwards.

Comment: @OneCricketeer okay. I think I found the solution on StackOverflow. I used:

sort = sorted(y, key=lambda x: int("".join([i for i in x if i.isdigit()])))
print(*sort, sep=", ")

and now my output is: U1, US2, U3, U5, U7, U8, U10, U20, U30

Comment: @OneCricketeer In his original example, yes, but I think it is better to present also a more general solution.

Comment: I wouldn't call numpy a general solution. `','.join(set(map(str, x)))` works for a list of numbers. Don't use String replacement

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
    for u in unique_values:
        print(u, end=", ")
```

with the pythonic:

```
    print(', '.join(unique_values))
```

Also generally better style to

```
return unique_values
```

and use

```
print(', '.join(unique(wells)))
```

Answer (score 0):

hope the below changes helps you :)

```
def unique(list1):
    unique_values = []
    for u in list1:
        if u not in unique_values:
            unique_values.append(u)
    return unique_values


wells = ["U1", "U1", "U3", "U3", "U3", "U5", "U5", "U5", "U7", "U7", "U7", "U7", "U7", "U8", "U8"]
req = unique(wells)
# prints in list format
print(f"The unique values from list are...: {req}")
# prints in string format
print(f"The unique values from list are...: {' '.join(req)}")
```

or the unique values can also be found out using `set(wells)`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues here: the trailing `,` as noted in the question, testing membership on an unsorted `list`. Use `str.join()` to handle the trailing comma, and don't even try to keep track of unique values and check if a new value has already been seen, just cast to `set`.

```py
def unique(list1):
    unique_values = set(list1)
    print(', '.join(sorted(unique_values)))


wells = ["U1", "U1", "U3", "U3", "U3", "U5", "U5", "U5", "U7", "U7", "U7", "U7", "U7", "U8", "U8"]
print("The unique values from list are...:", end=" ")
unique(wells)
```

Comment: Will a set guarantee the same sequence?

Comment: No, `set`S are unordered. For OP to get output sorted as in the question, the `set` must be sorted.